# How to send S/MIME encrypted mails from iOS with attachment?

Tags: ios, email, encryption, smime

How can I programmatically send an e-mail that is encrypted and signed using S/MIME?

How I currently do it:

- Prepare MFMailComposer
- Save the mail as a draft
- Switch to native mail app
- Open said draft
- Send draft (which is automatically encrypted/signed by opening it directly from the mail app)

This seems unproductive.

Why I want MFMailComposer: If internet is unavailable, mail will be put in the outbox and sent automatically as soon as internet is available. If there is a solution to my S/MIME problem that doesn't rely on MFMailComposer, it has to have this "automatic-send"-feature.

Comment: Any idea why Apple doesn't encrypt from the MFMailComposer?

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not allow you to sent emails without MFMailComposer (because it would be easy to abuse).
The only way I can think of is to send your email to your sever and and encrypt it there/send it. You can always check if there is no intenet connection and write the contents of the email to a temp file and send it when internet is available.

Hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: And how do I get it to my server encrypted?

Comment: There are several ways to encrypt data in Xcode (Cryptographic Message Syntax, S/MIME, even AES 256). You can use one of these to encrypt a NSString or NSData and then decode it server side. However you must be careful because exporting (using) encryption in your app is subject to some special rules when submitting your app. See more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html